# How to make Nuxt 3 resolve asset urls in css

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

How do I make Nuxt 3 resolve asset urls in css
I am converting a project from Nuxt 2 to 3 and this style remains the same
The style is loaded from nuxt config css

```
background: url('~assets/images/main-hero.webp') #4fcf8d no-repeat;
```

How do I make Nuxt 3 resolve it

I tried converting it to scss but same issue

I expected the url to be like "/_nuxt/img/7611483.webp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your CSS file should also be in `assets` folder. And in `nuxt.config.ts` (or `.js`, if you don't use TypeScirpt) you load it via: `css: ['@/assets/<path-to-your-file>']`.
2. You need to adjust image URL - either absolute from project root, or relative from where your css file resides.

So for example, lets say you have:

```
assets
├─ css
│  └─ main.css
└─ images
   └─ main-hero.webp
```

Then the url should be either `url('/assets/images/main-hero.webp')` or `url('../images/main-hero.webp')`.

Comment: Thanks. I realized `url('~/assets/images/main-hero.webp')` and `url('@/assets/images/main-hero.webp')` also work as well